# Can you connect the same AWS user pool to a React Native and React App?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify, aws-userpools

I have used AWS Amplify ("amplify add auth" in the terminal) to create a user pool in AWS Cognito with my React Native app but I don't know how to connect this same user pool to my React App. As far as I can see the Amplify Cli only gives options to create a new resource... Does anyone know how to connect it to an already existing/in use user pool?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrate existing AWS Cognito user pool into iOS project with Amplify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314155/integrate-existing-aws-cognito-user-pool-into-ios-project-with-amplify)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same pool with any frameworks. Make sure you pass in the right user pool configuration.

```
// AppSync client instantiation
const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
  url: AppSync.graphqlEndpoint,
  region: AppSync.region,
  auth: {
    // IAM
    // type: AUTH_TYPE.AWS_IAM,
    // credentials: () => Auth.currentCredentials(),

    // COGNITO USER POOLS
    type: AUTH_TYPE.AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS,
    jwtToken: async () => (await Auth.currentSession()).getAcceessToken().getJwtToken(),
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubt today and after searching, it's possible to use the same user pool.

Check the user pools configuration in your AWS Console and replace as it follows:

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
...

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    // REQUIRED only for Federated Authentication - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
    identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab',
    // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
    region: 'XX-XXXX-X',
    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
    userPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234',
    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string)
    userPoolWebClientId: 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k1l2m3'
  }
});
```